# Unable to resolve class.org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code, build.gradle

I opened up my build gradle because andoid emulator is not working and this is what I saw:

[image]

and this is the whole code:

build.gradle

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

I think this is the reason why android emulator is not working? What should I do to remove the error? Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue while building my old application. I just upgraded my react-native project to the newer version and deleted the old build folder from "App/android/build".

To upgrade your project, go to the official link:
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

1. select your version and the newer version you want to upgrade to.
2. after making changes to all the files mentioned there, delete the build folder.
   Then run command "npx react-native run-android"

NOTE: You might get an error while creating or deleting a file or directory because of wrong permissions. Use commands below:

1. In linux : chmod 755 "/path of the showing error of permission"
2. In windows : run cmd as administrator